# How to update Parse user information in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to update Parse user info in my app, but I don't know how to update it.

In my view controller I have `UsernameTxtField`, `NicknameTxtField`, `PasswordTxtField` and `UpdateButton`.

I want the user to set information inside the text field, then press the Update button to update them on Parse.com.

How should I do a query?

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
```

How can I do that? Can someone give me a code similar to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do the following to edit and save the `PFUser`'s data:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser(){
    currentUser["Username"] = "John Smith"
    //set other fields the same way....
    currentUser.saveInBackground()
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how to write in the text fields and each text field edit a column? after i click on update button

Comment: You have the `UITextField`'s on your Storyboard view controller, correct? If you just link them up to your view controller file, and upon hitting a submit button, save the text from the `UITextField` as I did above to the `currentUser`

Answer (score 0):

`PFUser` is a `PFObject` subclass, so you can easily edit it as any other Parse object.